# Variable in SQL ALTER TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to altering the AUTO_INCREMENT.
But now I'm stuck at this point.

I have calculate a number by using the idate(). This is $number.

Now I want to manipulate the AUTO_INCREMENT of a table with:

```
$sql = 'ALTER TABLE test AUTO_INCREMENT = $number';
```

What I have to do, to use this Variable in this SQL code?

Comment: What do you think is the result of manipulating the table's auto-increment number? You can't set it to a value less than the max value currently stored in the AI column. That is, you could set `AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` and it will not return an error, but it will immediately "round up" to MAX(id)+1. You can confirm this with `SHOW CREATE TABLE test\G`

Comment: I know that the value of the id can't be less then the max id. But i need to have a id and date combo. Like yymm01 (200101) and the next month then the first entry should have 200201. The manipulation of the id is the simplest way for me, because I have to custamize a running system.

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate of a past question. In short, you can't do this with auto-increment at least not with InnoDB (the default storage engine). If you want custom incrementing, then generate the values some other way, not with auto-increment.

Answer (score 1):

DON'T alter the AUTO_INCREMENT. Ever.

You are just confusing this unique identifier with a number. It is not a number. It should never be altered. Either you don't need this field at all or you should never touch it.